# Improve performance of a single page with lot of resources

Tags: javascript, performance, load

I'm having a website pretty heavy - containing around 700 lightbox. Each of them containing some good size pdf and mp4. It's all located in a same index.html ( js and css are external file)

The 'website' is running only locally on a machine. I can not use any local server like MAMP or other.

At the moment I'm having lof of errors in my console due to some path of files ( those pdf and mp4) being wrong.

When starting the website, it takes a good 45 seconds before to be able to naviguate correctly ( until all those path errors in the console have all appeared).

My question is the following:

- WHen all the path will be corrected, does the loading speed when starting be better ? Or it is not related ?
- all the pdf ( around 200) are being iframe, and the console display 1500 warnings due to that as:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf:

Does all those warnings are also slowing dane the loading of the website ? I know it s not best practice to embed iframe, but it s a requirement. any way to avoid this ? ( coudlnt not fine anything )

---

I know ideally the website should have been done using React or Angular to avoid this, but there is no way for such.

Using Ajax could help about this ? but the ideal solution is really something without using any web server. Does anyone would have any pointers how to improve this loading at the beginning ?

Thanks for all, it's really appreciate to have some opinion on this !

EDIT:

ERROR IN THE CONSOLE are 2 different types:

> GET
>   file:///Users/thibaultrolando/Documents/WORK/PROJECTS/JPCREATIVE/DEV/22-02/ALL%20MERGE/content/CARRIERS/Content/ClaimsPortal.mp4

this which appear around 200 times

+

> ```
> [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 77ms jquery.min.js:2  [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 63ms jquery.min.js:2
> ```

This 2 times

> [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 172ms

+

> Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking
>    event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the
>   page more responsive. See

Which appear 85 times

+

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf:

Which appear 1500 times

Answer (score 0):

Running locally with those sort of resources can pose some issues when there is no web server involved. Do you get these issues in all browsers? Can you update your question with your console errors?

Comment: Hi Sdefo70, thanks. I ve added the errors.

Any idea/  solutions ?

Thanks for all !

Comment: The GET message in the console is there any more information coming back with that? Are they only the MP4 files that get those errors?

Comment: Hi Sdefo, Only this, due to mp4 and pdf.

If i correct all path of this, should it increase the loading time do you think ?

Comment: That would help a little but I would Hazzard a guess that it's the number of I frames you are doing. As you mentioned in your question angular would be a less intensive solution.

Comment: okay, the problem is time delivery and ressources it is not going to be possible and IM trying to find a fast fix solutions.

What about AJAX do you think ?

Comment: all my lightboxes are divided in 5 distinc area.

To break those in 5 differetn ajax file. OR im open to any suggestion, what are you thinking ?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my suggestion that without code, difficult to suggest what is the exact issues.
Problem may be:

> 1: data is not in proper format.
>
> 2: for multiple loop.
>   so on...